# is it possible to use "or" in query part of update method in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Can I use or in query part of update method in mongodb.
If yes then what am I doing wrong because the upsert is not working.
I get two different type of result when I use and don't use or.
when I use or only the data.message is inserted and when I use don't use or all the data is inserted if it does not exist and it exist data.messages gets added to messages.

```
db.chatdata.update(
    {$or:[
      {'receiverId':data.receiver_id,
       'senderId':data.sender_id
      },
      {'receiverId':data.sender_id,
       'senderId':data.receiver_id
      }]
    },
    {$addToSet:{'messages':data.message}},
    {upsert:true},
    callback)
```

expected output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5986f850e1bf9b531154e52d"),
    "receiverId" : "5985864dd06db71fa4c2ce69",
    "senderId" : "59857707f6de9106fc936003",
    "messages" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5986f8509bda810a140e975d"),
                    "message" : "hello apple",
                    "time" : "1502017616523"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5986f8a19bda810a140e9768"),
                    "message" : "hello apple",
                    "time" : "1502017697484"
            }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
```

}

actual output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59872ec4e1bf9b531154eedd"),
    "messages" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59872ec4827f9737949589f3"),
                    "message" : "helo",
                    "time" : "1502031556694"
            }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
```

}

Comment: Please edit to show your output (both expected and actual.

Comment: Possible yes, but at some point you need to decide which of "sender" or "receiver" you actually want to "upsert", since either way around one of the value sequences needs to be chosen and `$or` does not supply enough information to create those properties, hence why they are missing in the result. Your particular issue here though appears to be that an "expected match" is not actually matching and therefore not "updating" but **upserting** instead . So you appear to have a mismatch on the actual data present in `data` to the values actually stored.